transmission torrent clients : GUI apps and Web UI show different file sets
Running transmission with all default settings except for Downloads directory which I set in /var/lib/transmission/.config/transmission-remote/settings.json
Accessing with the web-ui and transmission-remote cli at localhost:9091 I see the same two torrents.
Accessing with the GUI views -- transmission-gtk and transmission-qt --  I see five different torrents. The download directory for both these views is exactly the same as the one set in settings.json
Adding a new torrent to either view adds that torrent to only that view.
If I add a torrent through the web ui only the web ui and the cli will show it, and if I add the torrent through a GUI only the GUI views will show it.
Looking at that directory through a shell directory listing I see all the files.
What's going on? I want GUI,web,CLI to show the same set of files. Is this possible?
On Arch Linux 6.8.4-arch1-1


libtransmission 4.0.5-1   
transmission-cli 4.0.5-1  
transmission-gtk 4.0.5-1  
transmission-qt 4.0.5-1   
transmission-remote-gtk 1.5.1-1 

